# Synchronizing postgresql database access on node js server

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a node js server running and configured to auto-scale. This server is accessing a postgresql database on AWS which I'd like to version. The goal here is to allow me to push a server update in code that will alter the tables as needed. What I've done so far is created a `BaseDatabase` class that connects to the database when the server starts (before I start the express js app so there's no network traffic yet).

Upon connection to the database, I check the current version using (in typescript):

```
let transactionComplete = false;
try {
  await client.query("BEGIN");
  let currentVersion = await client.query("SELECT current_setting('info.version')::int");
  if (currentVersion < version) {
    try {
      await upgradeDatabase(client, currentVersion, version);
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
    }
  }
  await client.query(`SELECT set_config('info.version', ${version}, false)`);
  transactionComplete = true;
} catch (e) {
  try {
    await createDatabase(client);
    transactionComplete = true;
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle error
  }
} finally {
  if (transactionComplete) {
    await client.query('COMMIT');
  } else {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK');
  }
  client.release();
}
```

For all my tests this works, I can run multiple instances of my server on different ports and I'm able to create/update my database only once. I worry that I'm just lucky. I have a feeling that even though this is a single transaction, it's conditioned on the first `SELECT` which resolves before the final `COMMIT`, I think. It seems like the correct way to do this would be to us conditionals inside my query and execute everything together. I've been able to create something like:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
IF (SELECT current_setting('info.version')::int) < ${version} THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'database requires update';
END IF;
END;
$$;
```

The above works and I believe would be entirely atomic if I could get my upgrade statements inside the if. The issue is that I don't know which statements I need until I query `info.version`. Is there anyway to lock the entire database while I make these queries? Or maybe synchronize all my node js server instances? Or something else I haven't thought of?

The final goal here is that I'd be able to put, in code, any changes to the database and they'd be executed once when I push a new server version. I can then have code-review etc with my team prior to making database changes and also have a reproducible way to replicate my prod environment locally.

Comment: Posting a question on a suspicion versus facts is poking holes in the sky. Determine the problem first, and then look for a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The problem is that I'd like to be able to version my database and modify it using JavaScript. My concern is that what I have doesn't hold up to synchronization. My question is how can I perform the same operations in trying to do in a way that's safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that appears to be working:

```
// This is actually a bit more complex to allow for the first instance when
// info.version is not yet defined.
let currentVersion: number = await client.query(
    "SELECT current_setting('info.version')");
if (this.version === currentVersion) {
  return;
}
let query: string = currentVersion === null
    ? await this.onCreate(client)
    : await this.onUpgrade(client currentVersion, this.version);
query = this.getSqlStatment(currentVersion, this.version, query);
try {
  await client.query(query);
} catch (e) {
} finally {
  client.release();
}

private getSqlStatement(fromVersion: number, toVersion: number, query: string): string {
  return `DO \$\$
DECLARE version integer;
BEGIN
version := current_setting('info.version')::integer;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN SQLSTATE '42704' THEN version := NULL;
IF version ${fromVersion ? `= ${fromVersion} : "IS NULL"} THEN
  ${query}
  PERFORM set_config('info.version', '${toVersion}', false);
END IF;
END;
\$\$`;
}
```